# How do I get all the coins from my Exodus Wallet to show in my Trust Wallet? Trust Wallet only shows some balances

Tags: wallets, trustwallet

Ive been using EXODUS wallet. I decided to try TRUST wallet. When I used my 12 WORDS PHRASE to set up the TRUST wallet, Only some coins shown. I see my BITCOIN, but I don;t see my SOLANA. I can add SOLANA in my TRUST wallet LIST, but it wont show the balance. This also the case for other coins such as SHIBA INU. How can I solve this problem?